# How to create multiple custom fields in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to set up 3 custom fields on my homepage where the user can update the colours so ideally I would like `$primary_color`, `$secondary_color` and `$tertiary_color` which when updated change 3 css styles that are in the `<head>` of my page but right now I'm a little unsure how to do this. Im not sure if this kind of code needs to be inside 'the loop' and I'm also unsure how I can combine the custom fields so code doesn't get replicated for no reason. If anyone could explain what I need to do that would be great. Here's an example of the code I'm trying to use at the moment:

```
<?php $primary_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, "primary-color", false); ?>
<?php $secondary_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, "secondary-color", false); ?>
<?php $tertiary_color = get_post_meta($post->ID, "tertiary-color", false); ?>
<style>
    .primary-color {
        background-color: <?php echo($primary_color) ?>;
    }

    .secondary-color {
        background-color: <?php echo($secondary_color) ?>;
    }

    .tertiary-color {
        background-color: <?php echo($tertiary_color) ?>;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't usually do this but I have an answer for you previous question. Why did you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use on your page in the wordpress dashboard the option 'screen options' and there choose custom field. There you can give them the nam primary_color etc... maybe that solves your problem?